# How to properly compare doubles in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Have noticed the following behaviour when trying to compare two doubles.

Given the following basic script:

```
[double]$maxValue = 1.5
[double]$startValue = 1.2
[double]$counter = $startValue

while ($counter -lt $maxValue) {
    Write-Host $counter
    $counter += 0.1
}
```

Output:

```
1.2
1.3
1.4
```

If i change the while statement to use less than or equals:
    while ($counter -le $maxValue) {

Output:

```
1.2
1.3
1.4
```

Which is exactly the same as above and thus missing the expected last value of "1.5" at the end.

How can i properly compare two doubles in powershell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest not using `double` to start with. Use `System.Decimal` (which may have an alias in PowerShell - I'm not sure). It looks like you're interested in exact decimal values, so use an appropriate type.

The reason you're not seeing 1.5 is that the closest double to 0.1 is *very slightly larger* than 0.1... so you're actually getting numbers like 1.2000000001, 1.3000000002, 1.400000002 - and then 1.500000003 is *not* less than or equal to 1.5.

See my articles on [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, suspected something like that was going on just couldn't determine what. Looks like decimal does exist, updating the code with [decimal] instead of [double] and it works as expected.